# AngularJS filter on date, display only time if year/month/day the same

Tags: angularjs, date

I'm new to AngularJS, for the item I have beginning date and ending date. If the year/month/day are the same for both, I'd like to only display time (HH.mm) for ending date. If they're different I want to display everything. Like this:

```
{{item.bDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'}} - {{item.eDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm' }}
```

Any hints on how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your html to:

```
 {{item.bDate | date: getDateFormat(item.bDate, item.eDate) }}-
 {{item.eDate | date: getDateFormat(item.bDate, item.eDate) }}
```

and creates this function in your controller:

```
$scope.getDateFormat = function(bDate,eDate){
    var beginDate = new Date(bDate);
    var endDate = new Date(eDate);

    if (beginDate.getDate() == endDate.getDate())
        return 'HH:mm';
    else
        return 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm';
}
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that Date.getDate() returns the day of the month and not the date part (it's a terribly named function).

Comment: @GruffBunny, do you know how can we do that? So we need to compare day, month and year?

Comment: You could check the day, month and year for both dates (as in my solution). Another solution would be to call setHours(0,0,0,0) on both dates to clear the time and then doing the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new custom filter:

```
.filter('enddate', function($filter){

    var filterDate = $filter('date');

    function datesEqual(endDate, startDate){
        return endDate.getDate() == startDate.getDate() &&
            endDate.getMonth() == startDate.getMonth() &&
            endDate.getYear() == startDate.getYear();
    }

    return function(endDate, startDate){
        return datesEqual(endDate,startDate) ? filterDate(endDate, 'HH:mm') : filterDate(endDate, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    };
})
```

View:

```
{{item.bDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm' }} - {{item.eDate | enddate: item.bDate}}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/4X7M2/)</kbd>